# swingにおいて component must be shown とIllegalStateException になる原因を知りたい

Tags: java, swing

現在swingベースのライブラリを使用した現場での開発をしておりまして、
**検索ボタン（SearchBox）を押下して、そこで項目を選択し、呼び出し元画面に戻ると選択項目の値が設定されるという動きです。**
（少し機密情報のためスクショやコードを載せづらいため、文章でわかりづらくすみません。）

その際になぜか「 **java.lang.IllegalStateException:component must be shown** 」と例外が発生してしまいます。

**その原因をまず追求したい**です。
考えられる可能性があることを教えていただけると助かります。
今提供できる情報に関しましても整理しているので、追記していくつもりです。

IllegalStateException自体が「メソッドが間違った時間に呼び出されたことを示す」非チェック例外なので、メソッドの呼び出し方に関しても確認してみます。

Comment: IllegalStateExceptionが「メソッドが間違った時間に呼び出されたことを示す」という認識は何に基づいていますか？
”component must be shown”エラーメッセージから受ける印象は、非表示(not shown)のコンポーネントを操作した事がきっかけになった例外なのですが。

Comment: Illegalexceptionの意味を検索しているのそのように示している記述があり、そのような解釈をしていました。非表示のコンポーネントを操作したという事を広くとれば間違ったタイミングで操作されたと解釈もできなくもないのでそこまで大きく外れていなくもないような。ある意味その「非表示のコンポーネントを操作したことがきっかけ」という言語化した事実がまず一歩目のとして知りたかったことです。

Answer (score 0):

結果として、この質問に対しては解決しました。
子画面の処理において、親画面が表示されていないタイミングで親画面を操作しようとしてエラーになっていました。valueChangeイベント内でそのような実装がされていたのですが、そこを修正する方向性で進めたいと思います。